How to force an image size to match the size of the other column in bootstrap
So i am trying to get this image to fit the size of the the other column. So basically i have a row and 2 column let's just say it is 6 unit width each and i wonder how to make the height of the image fit the size of the other column which has text as the value.
this is the snippet of said code


.home-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.home-text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
<section class="home-featured">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-2">
      <img src="assets/images/Home-section.jpg" alt="Home-section" class="home-image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-start d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
          <h1>Last A Lifetime</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row main-content-description">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
          <p class="home-text-justify">A pocket watch is a classic masterpiece made from high quality material that could last a lifetime. Pocket watches are often characterized by their intricate craftsmanship, which may include ornate designs, engravings, or precious materials.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row main-content-brand">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 new-home main-content-brand-description">
              <p>Made Of</p>
              <h6 class="home-text my-3">White Crystal</h6>
              <p>From Papua</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 new-home main-content-brand-description">
              <p>Manufactured By</p>
              <h6 class="home-text my-3">Watches</h6>
              <p>For The Best</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>



This is the photo of the current code Current
This is the expectation Expectation
I also wonder do we need to resize an image we are going to put in our website? or it is actually fine to just put whatever image size and then use css to resize it?

It is difficult to check the problem with the picture. The font looks different and the sizes all look different. The attached code is so insufficient that it is difficult to check normally. Please provide more information.

If you want the image to be 100% width and 100% height, surely it might get distorted on different screen width. But let's start with that. We will use relative on the container so then we can use absolute for the image taking 100% of the height (using top: 0 and bottom: 0 possibly).


body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: block;
  
  /* Clearfix (!!) source: "unknown" */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <p>Lorem ipsum warning: It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum warning: It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>    


  </div>
  <div class="col-6 img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
</div>



Now since it works for the height, you can decide on "width" for the image yourself, maybe "auto". Another idea is to use the image as background for the img-container element so you can use background-size which is quite flexible.
